# Django - ImportError: No module named wsgi

Tags: python, django

Last computer (it broke) used python 2.6, now I'm using python 2.7. I copied the old `dist-packages` from `/python2.6/` to `/python2.7/`. That is, I did not install Django again, I thought copying everything was enough.

I'm getting this error when I attempt to access my Apache 2.4 server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[:error] [pid 13427:tid 140433508034304] [client 192.168.1.20:50087]   File "/var/www/tbg/django.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[:error] [pid 13427:tid 140433508034304] [client 192.168.1.20:50087]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[:error] [pid 13427:tid 140433508034304] [client 192.168.1.20:50087] ImportError: No module named wsgi
```

This is my `django.wsgi`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path = ['/var/www/tbg'] + sys.path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tbg.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Let me know if you need more informatino.

Comment: You can't just copy `dist-packages` from one version of Python to another - you'll need to reinstall everything. The ABI changes between minor versions (i.e., 2.6 and 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4, etc.), so any `.pyc` files that are present may break your programs.

Comment: Oh, okay. Even all the small extensions inside dist-packages? Not only Django?

Comment: yup. You don't need to worry about upgrading micro versions - 2.7.3 to 2.7.9, for example, but minor (and major) version changes can, and most likely will, be incompatible.

Comment: What about Django projects inside /var/www?

Comment: I think it'd be better if I just stuck with 2.6. How would I do that?

Comment: I would go through and delete any `.pyc` files in those projects just to be safe. As long as you're using the same version of Django, you shouldn't have to edit the code any.

Comment: Let's continue this in chat. Please join the [Python chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) and ping me `@MattDMo` and we can sort this out.